# Currently used file without interop

Tags: c#, com-interop

I have an application that is checking for active opened window and is returning the process of a window and also the window title.

This two things are generally enough. However I also want to know the file name and it's file path the process is using.

```
Process.StartInfo.FileName();
```

This was not working for me so I decided a different approach. I am taking the file and file Path from the window title if it exist and form Win32_Process table I have pull command line that process was started by.

```
private static string GetCommandLine(Process process)
    {
        var commandLine = new StringBuilder(process.MainModule.FileName);

        commandLine.Append(" ");
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + process.Id))
        {
            foreach (var @object in searcher.Get())
            {
                commandLine.Append(@object["CommandLine"]);
                commandLine.Append(" ");
            }
        }

        return commandLine.ToString();
    }
```

Soon I find out that this is also not enough. So I started to implement a lot of IterOp dll for example Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and also Photoshop.

```
var ps = (Photoshop.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Photoshop.Application");

            return ps.ActiveDocument.FullName;
```

My question is if there is a way how to bypassed interOp files and use something more generic?

PS:
I know of the similar application for Mac OS that is using build in accessibility functions. Is there a windows version of accessibility, that I can use in code and would preform this particular task?